# Замена элементов массива

Tags: php

Есть массив $arQuestion["ANSWERS"] внутри которого есть PERSENT, как мне его заменить на значения из массива $persent?

```
foreach($arQuestion["ANSWERS"] as $k=>$v){
  if($v["PERCENT"])array_replace ($arQuestion["ANSWERS"][$k]["PERCENT"],    $persent[$k]);
}
```

Печатаю предварительно массив $arQuestion["ANSWERS"]

```
Array
(
    [40] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 33
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 100
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 17
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 50
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 17
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 50
        )

)

Array
(
    [42] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 33
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 100
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 17
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 50
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [CHANNEL_ID] => 1
            [PERCENT] => 17
            [BAR_PERCENT] => 50
        )

)
```

Comment: `foreach($arQuestion["ANSWERS"] as $k => &$v) {
  if($v["PERCENT"]) $v["PERCENT"] = $persent[$k];
}`

Comment: как поправить код?

Comment: А как выглядит $persent ?

Comment: Array(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 25
)

Array(
    [0] => 40
    [1] => 40
    [2] => 20
)

Comment: конечно - у первого массива индексы от 40 и выше, а у вторго 0,1,2.... Как строить соответствие? Просто берем по порядку?

Comment: а если вот так написать array_values($arQuestion["ANSWERS"]); ?

Comment: `foreach($arQuestion["ANSWERS"] as $k => &$v) { if($v["PERCENT"]) $v["PERCENT"] = array_shift($persent); }`

Answer (score 1):

Если индексы массивов совпадают, то так:

```
foreach($arQuestion["ANSWERS"] as $k=>$v){
    if (isset($v['PERSENT'])) $arQuestion["ANSWERS"][$k]["PERSENT"] = $persent[$k];
}
```

Comment: скобок нет. ошибка в коде.

Comment: @Naumov в коде нет синтаксических ошибок. Не уверены в чём-то, не давайте ценных комментариев.

Comment: ошибка есть она не синтаксическая.

Comment: $ - пропущенный заметил, скобки не нужны.

Comment: аргументируйте ненужность скобок, прилинкуйте офф источники почему они не нужны?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php